# Подскажите python библиотеку для работы с etherium

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек, ethereum

Нужно автономно узнавать баланс.
Библиотека blockcypher работает только с bitcoin, Litecoin, Dogecoin, Dash, URO.

Comment: Почему бы просто не воспользоваться API любой из бирж?

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека `request` со всякими `get`'ами, `post`'ами и так далее. Ищите API на биржах и отправляйте запросы, которые вам нужны, через python.